# object detection model being trained is stuck but no error message is shown

Tags: object-recognition, 3d-object-recognition

tensorflow objection detection model im working on currently is stuck, i cannot figure out where ive gone wrong as all the lines before it executed properly.this line simply wont execute beyond this point and it gets disconnected due to inactivity. what may be causing this line to take so much time to execute?

[image: the line of code being executed]

[image: the point upto which the code executes(its been stuck at this point for more than an hour)]

[image]

Comment: Please post your used input variables (e.g. `num_steps`) and to help others to find this issue in the future if they have a similar problem, it's better if you provide the logs as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: please do not post a screenshot of text ... post the text instead ... format same as code ... only the third image can stay an image because popup dialogs usually cannot be copy/pasted